# Error in the call of the repository - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jsf

People, I need of a help! I'm trying to save an form data of users, but i recept this error when i submit the form in my page jsf with .

The error happen in the line 27, when i call the instruction "userService.addUser(user)" of the method save.

Bellow I will put  the code and stracktrace for you look at.

Stracktrace:

```
ago 14, 2018 1:28:47 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.jamming.controller.RegisterUserMB.save(RegisterUserMB.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

RegisterUserMB.class

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScope
public class RegisterUserMB {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private User user = new User();
    private ProfileUser profileUser = new ProfileUser();

    private String confirmPw;

    public String save() {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "";

    }
```

UserService.class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository<User> userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the User class have a default constructor?

Comment: You are using JSF Dependency injection instead Spring DI, The UserService class won't be injected using @Autowred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different **Content Dependency Injection** in the same application:

**Spring DI** and the **JSF CDI**

Each of these frameworks manage its Beans Factory on it own, theirs factory are isolated one between other.

you need to specify which of them will manage the Dependency Injection.

> **SECOND EDIT**

You must specify Spring will take the control over the injection doing two things:

**1)** The first one is to use `@Controller` and `@Scope` annotations instead of JSF annotations in order to just use spring beans.

**2)** and The second one is specify to JSF that Spring will manage the El expression language in the views

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: Oh, really? what you recomed to I use?

I've been debugging my code and noticed that the @autowired annotation is not working. Soon, the useService is staying null.

Comment: If you want to use both framework you must specify jsf that spring will manage the injection, you can achieve this adding a configuration in the faces-config.xml file

Comment: Great Jorge, worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `user` property of your `RegisterUserMB` class is being set to `null` somewhere.

Comment: yes, I saw this. But I do not know how solve it. 
So far only discovery with the annotation @autowired don't working, and the userService is null during the call.